# enum to bytes / bytes to enum?

Tags: serialization, rust, enums

I'm trying to build a generic Rust server / client (tcp and udp) system.

The initial idea is to allow the user to create an enum as the messages packets.
But this requires a way to serialize / deserialize them as bytes, and I can't really find anything online about it. Let's consider :

```rust
enum Messages {
    Welcome,
    Position(f32, f32),
    Damages(u8),
}
```

First thing, on the serialize part, I can't find how to know what each variants size is, and how to write down all of them.

```rust
fn send<E>(message: E) {
    // create a Vec<u8> from the enum message, and an id (enum variant id as usize ?)
}
```

And on the other size, I don't even know how to rebuild such an enum :

```rust
fn message_received<E>(data: Vec<u8>, id: usize) -> E {
    // get the E enum variant from the id
    // write all the enum fields with the data
}
```

Of course, the idea is that the enum is the same on server and client side.

Seeing how I have no idea how to do all this, I'm wondering if this entire idea is not the way to go ? But then, how one would implement such a generic message system ?

Comment: Usually you'd add the encoding to the enum itself, possibly through `serde` using one of the efficient common binary serialisations as your wire format. [The serde website has an incomplete list of data formats](https://serde.rs/#data-formats).

Comment: `serde` is indeed the way to go in most cases. But just for completeness, have a look at `rkyv` and what `#[repr(C)]` does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using the [serde](https://crates.io/crates/serde) (Serialize-Deserialize) crate.

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use serde_json;

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
enum Messages {
    Welcome,
    Position(f32, f32),
    Damages(u8),
}

fn serialize(message: Messages) -> Vec<u8> {
    serde_json::to_vec(&message).unwrap()
}

fn deserialize(bytes: &[u8]) -> Messages {
    serde_json::from_slice(bytes).unwrap()
}

fn main() {
    // on the server
    let message: Messages = Messages::Position(1.2, 3.4);
    let bytes: Vec<u8> = serialize(message);
    println!("{bytes:?}"); // [123, 34, 80, 111, ...]

    // on the client
    let message_deserialized: Messages = deserialize(&bytes);
    println!("{message_deserialized:?}"); // Position(1.2, 3.4)
}
```

As you can see this method uses JSON as an intermediary to store your enum's data. In some applications, this might be too slow (a u64 is 8 bytes in your code, but once converted to JSON it takes 1 byte per character in base 10, increasing quite a lot the total size of the message, and the transfer time as well), in which case creating custom functions might be necessary.

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Messages {
    Welcome,
    Position(f32, f32),
    Damages(u8),
}

fn serialize(message: Messages) -> Vec<u8> {
    match message {
        Messages::Welcome => vec![0],
        Messages::Position(x, y) => {
            let mut buffer = vec![1];
            buffer.extend_from_slice(&x.to_le_bytes());
            buffer.extend_from_slice(&y.to_le_bytes());
            buffer
        }
        Messages::Damages(damages) => {
            vec![2, damages]
        }
    }
}

fn deserialize(bytes: &[u8]) -> Messages {
    match bytes[0] {
        0 => Messages::Welcome,
        1 => {
            let x = f32::from_le_bytes([bytes[1], bytes[2], bytes[3], bytes[4]]);
            let y = f32::from_le_bytes([bytes[5], bytes[6], bytes[7], bytes[8]]);
            Messages::Position(x, y)
        }
        2 => {
            Messages::Damages(bytes[1])
        }
        _ => panic!("Unknown message"),
    }
}

fn main() {
    // on the server
    let message: Messages = Messages::Position(1.2, 3.4);
    let bytes: Vec<u8> = serialize(message);
    println!("{bytes:?}"); // [1, 154, 153, 153, 63, 154, 153, 89, 64] (way smaller !)

    // on the client
    let message_deserialized: Messages = deserialize(&bytes);
    println!("{message_deserialized:?}"); // Position(1.2, 3.4)
}
```

The example above is a possible way to manually implement this system. But I would suggest using the first method if it isn't critically bound by time, as the second one is more time-consuming to write and waaaaaay more prone to errors.

Whether using enums is the way to go, it will depend on what your are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks ! This is indeed what I was looking for. However, speed is important in my case (I'm doing the network system for a game engine) so I started implementing my own serialization / deserialization system.