# Rust - Get Enum-With-Data Ordinal

Tags: rust, enums

I'm trying to serialize an enum. I plan to serialize by first encoding the ordinal of the enum, then the values very similarly to [enum to bytes / bytes to enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74232360). The answer to that question involved using a crate, serde; I would like to avoid using this crate.

It seems that there are two types of enums: with data and without, that are incompatible in some ways. It appears possible to get ordinal values from enums without data using `as u8` simply enough. A value comes back from `as u8` on enum variants with data, but enum variants without data (when other enum variants have data) fail to compile:

https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=2f6a4e8507a59d451546a69407bc0d77

```rust
#[repr(u8)]
enum Enumeration {
    One=0,
}

#[repr(u8)]
enum Other {
    Twelve(String)=4,
    Thirteen=5,
}
fn main() {
    println!("Got unsigned {:?}", Enumeration::One as u8);
    println!("Got other {:?}", Other::Twelve as u8);
    // Uncommenting the next line produces a compiler error
    //println!("Got other {:?}", Other::Thirteen as u8);
}
```

(I get the impression that the values coming back from enum variants with data are not useful.)

How do I get the ordinal for enum variants with data?

Comment: You don't get the discriminant of `Twelve`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman That's right. I'm a little surprised by that after reading "Given that rustc guarantees that `#[repr(u16)]` enumerations start with their discriminant stored as a `u16`..." (https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2363/files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on

> Given that rustc guarantees that #[repr(u16)] enumerations start with their discriminant stored as a u16...

here: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2363/files, the first byte of the enumeration value should be the underlying `u8`. So...

https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=21e3ab42f76ccbc05b6b61560cbd29ec

```rust
#[repr(u8)]
enum MyOption {
    Option(String),
    NotOption,
}

fn get_ordinal(option: MyOption) -> u8 {
    let ptr_to_option = (&option as *const MyOption) as *const u8;
    unsafe {
        *ptr_to_option
    }
}

fn main() {
    let option = MyOption::Option("Yolo".to_string());
    let not_option = MyOption::NotOption;
    println!("ordinal for Option is {}; NotOption is {}", 
        get_ordinal(option), get_ordinal(not_option));
}
```

output `ordinal for Option is 0; NotOption is 1`.

Answer (score 2):

TLDR; you're casting a function pointer to a `u8`, not what you want. Use `serde` or similar to achieve your goal if you want to.

---

So, running clippy on your code gives a very good indication of what's going on here:

```
warning: casting function pointer `Other::Twelve` to `u8`, which truncates the value
  --> src/main.rs:13:32
   |
13 |     println!("Got other {:?}", Other::Twelve as u8);
   |                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: try: `Other::Twelve as usize`
   |
   = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#fn_to_numeric_cast_with_truncation
   = note: `#[warn(clippy::fn_to_numeric_cast_with_truncation)]` on by default

warning: cast of an enum tuple constructor to an integer
  --> src/main.rs:13:32
   |
13 |     println!("Got other {:?}", Other::Twelve as u8);
   |                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#cast_enum_constructor
   = note: `#[warn(clippy::cast_enum_constructor)]` on by default
```

So, that's probably not what you want.

If we dig deeper into the nomicon, we can find [this article](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/other-reprs.html#repru-repri):

> If the enum has fields, the effect is similar to the effect of repr(C) in that there is a defined layout of the type. This makes it possible to pass the enum to C code, or access the type's raw representation and directly manipulate its tag and fields. See the RFC for details.
>
> [...]
>
> Adding an explicit repr(u*), repr(i*), or repr(C) to an enum with fields suppresses the null-pointer optimization, like:
>
> ```rust
> enum MyOption<T> {
>     Some(T),
>     None,
> }
>
> #[repr(u8)]
> enum MyReprOption<T> {
>     Some(T),
>     None,
> }
>
> assert_eq!(8, size_of::<MyOption<&u16>>());
> assert_eq!(16, size_of::<MyReprOption<&u16>>());
> ```

If you want to read what you can do with that, follow the RFC: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2195-really-tagged-unions.md#guide-level-explanation